# Google Maps V3: Placing Infowindow Box in Fixed Position

Tags: jquery, css, google-maps-api-3, fixed, infowindow

EDIT: I have a code that places markers on google maps with associated infowindows. What I'd like to do is to fix the infowindow box. I created a container div with sub-divs for the infowindow which is absolute and one for the map which is relative. For some reason I get an infobox on the map rather than above it and the infobox text isn't cointained in the defined box. The text goes outside of the boundaries.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eboard10/KgPeN/5/)

**HTML**

`<div id="container">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="infowindow"></div>
</div>`

**CSS**

```
      #container {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
      }
      #map_canvas {
        position: relative;
        height: 400px;
        width: 400px;
      }
      #infowindow {
        position: absolute;
        left:   0px;
        top:    0px;
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
        overflow: auto;
        border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
        border-right: 1px solid #999;
        box-shadow: 0 1px 1px #cccccc;
      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a `absolute` position. When you wan't the box to be placed above the map simply place it before the map in the document: http://jsfiddle.net/KgPeN/10/

Comment: thanks! What if instead I want the box to appear in the same position but on the map rather than above it, do I then need to use 'absolute' for the map or is there another way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean...when it's on the map it's not above the map...so it's a different position.

Comment: yes, that's what I'm asking, whether it's possible to place the box over the map so that part of the map will be covered by the box.

Comment: It's possible. Of course you can use CSS to place the box whereever you want to, but I would suggest to use a [**custom control**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls), the box will have a fixed position on the map, no matter where you place the map.

Comment: you're a star! Will look into the custom control.

Comment: May I ask why the need to add the [0] inside the push? And could you not just call the #facebook instead of the div? map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push($('<div id="infowindow"/>')[0]);

Comment: The pushed object is expected to be a HTMLElement, without the `[0]` it would be a jQuery-object.  Related to the `#facebook`: I'm not sure what you mean, there is no such element.

Answer (score 1):

got this to work with bootstrap, placing the infowindow over both the map and the navbar, similar to this map: [WTAMU Map](http://map.wtamu.edu/map/?id=458#!ct/4072)

However the above answer lacks a close control. default infowindow contains this, but I am uncertain how to specifically call it withing the infowindow div.